# Using stats command in gnuplot shows min and max to be zero for exponentially small values

Tags: plot, gnuplot

My data file `data.dat` looks like this:

```
1e-23   1e-23   1e-27   2e-28
2e-22   4e-23   1e-23   4e-23
3e-21   1e-23   1e-24   6e-23
4e-32   1e-23   1e-25   8e-30
```

Using `gnuplot`, I use `stats "data.dat" matrix` to find minimum and maximum values in the above array (data file); both values are shown zero. I am guessing `stats` is reading exponentially low values as zero. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: the command (Gnuplot 4.6.2) `stats 'data.dat' matrix nooutput;print STATS_min, STATS_max` gives me `4.00000009496891e-32 2.99999990479657e-21` which seems to be compatible with the provided data...

Comment: I just checked and one value in my original date file is of order of e-322. Could you please make a quick check what you get as minimum if you replace, say first value in the above array, by 1e-322?

Comment: And if it is this value, which is making the minimum to be zero, how do I tell stats command to ignore this one value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you execute the command

```
stats 'data.dat' matrix
```

the output minimum/maximum reported is indeed:

```
  Minimum:            0.0000 [ 0 3 ]
  Maximum:            0.0000 [ 0 2 ]
  COG:                0.1157      1.9057
```

This is due to the strategy Gnuplot uses for formatting the values in the `stats` output. The relevant function is:

```
static char*
fmt( char *buf, double val )
{
    if ( isnan(val) )
  sprintf( buf, "%11s", "undefined");
    else if ( fabs(val) < 1e-14 ) //<-- HERE
  sprintf( buf, "%11.4f", 0.0 );
    else if ( fabs(log10(fabs(val))) < 6 )
  sprintf( buf, "%11.4f", val );
    else
  sprintf( buf, "%11.5e", val );
    return buf;
}
```

this means that if a value in absolute value is smaller than `1E-14`, it will show just zero...

To get the raw values, you might use the `STATS_min`/`STATS_max` variables:

```
gnuplot> print STATS_min, STATS_max
4.00000009496891e-32 2.99999990479657e-21
```

EDIT:

The `stats 'filename' matrix` seems to behave slightly differently than the "ordinary" `stats` executed per column:

```
fname = 'data.dat'

stats fname nooutput
N = STATS_columns

#specify which values to include in the minimum calculation    
cond(val) = 1 #(abs(val) > 1E-30)

#process each column individually and determine the global minimum

#if there are no values, set the minimum to +inf
globalMin = real('inf')

do for [i=1:N] {
  stats fname using (cond(column(i))?column(i):NaN) nooutput

  #due to cond( ), there might not be any records, so one needs to check
  if(STATS_records) { 
    globalMin = (STATS_min < globalMin)?STATS_min:globalMin
  }
}
print globalMin
```

Comment: I just checked and one value in my original date file is of order of e-322. With `STATS_min` this is shown to be zero. `STATS_max` works fine, now. Any idea how to ignore this one "rogue" value in all my files?

Comment: @AK02 indeed, `stats ... matrix` seems not to detect these small values (which are by the way pretty close to the limits of the double precision). Calculating the minimum per column (see the edit) improves it slightly...